# Why aren't the neo4j style profiles persisting?

Tags: neo4j

I am using the Neo4j webadmin and have created a custom style profile. However, when open the webadmin in another browser, I do not see any style profiles listed. Is there something special I need to do in order for these profiles to appear in the list in my other browser session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The profiles are stored in local cookies.

Comment: My goodness. So every developer needs to create his own set of profiles? Ech.